# How to untoggle a dropdown by clicking elsewhere in the page - stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu, toggle

I wonder if anyone can help to finally resolve an issue I brought up on SO a while back.

I am unable to untoggle these dropdown menus by clicking outside of the button, or anywhere else on the page.

***Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZHEd/1/).***

I've seen folks using `stopPropagaton()` but am unsure how to apply it here.

Any ideas how to do this?

My toggling code:

```
var cur = null;
$(".toggle").click(function(e){
    $('#nav ul:visible').hide();

    if(cur == null || cur.currentTarget != e.currentTarget)
    {
        if(cur != null)
        {
            $(cur.currentTarget)
                .children('a:first').children('span').removeClass('fc-state-active');
        }

        cur = e;
        $(cur.currentTarget)
            .children('a:first').children('span').addClass('fc-state-active');
        $(cur.currentTarget)
            .children('ul').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(cur.currentTarget)
            .children('a:first').children('span').removeClass('fc-state-active');

        cur = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: The best solution I found is [stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element). I don't think any other solution would be soo simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following should work for you. This utilizes jQuery's focusout() function:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $('#nav ul:visible').hide();
    $('span.fc-state-active').removeClass('fc-state-active');
    $(this).children('a:first').children('span').addClass('fc-state-active');
    $(this).children('ul').show();
}).focusout(function(){
    $('#nav ul:visible').hide();
    $('span.fc-state-active').removeClass('fc-state-active');
});
```

And here's an updated fiddle: [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znhAC/1/)

**EDIT: The following works in FF & Chrome**
New Fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znhAC/2/)

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $('#nav ul:visible').hide();
    $('span.fc-state-active').removeClass('fc-state-active');
    $(this).children('a:first').children('span').addClass('fc-state-active');
    $(this).children('ul').show();
    hide = false;
}); 
$(document).click(function(){
    if(hide){
        $('#nav ul:visible').hide();
        $('span.fc-state-active').removeClass('fc-state-active');
    }
    hide = true;
});
```

Reason: `$(document).click()` is called *after* `$(".toggle").click()`

**EDIT 2: The working fiddle can be found here: [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znhAC/5/)**

```
var hide;
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    var active_span = $(this).children('a:first').children('span');   
    var active_ul = $(this).children('ul');

    $(active_span).toggleClass('fc-state-active');
    $("span.fc-state-active").not(active_span).removeClass('fc-state-active');
    $(active_ul).toggle();
    $("#nav ul:visible").not(active_ul).hide();
    hide = false;   
});
$(document).click(function(){
    if(hide){
        $('#nav ul:visible').hide();
        $('span.fc-state-active').removeClass('fc-state-active');
    }
    hide = true;
});
```

Comment: @D Franks, this does not seem to work on Chrome (works on FF) - any idea why?

Comment: It seems Chrome doesn't like to fire focusout(). I'm currently looking for a fix for that.

Comment: Found the solution. It's doesn't use the focusout() function, but it works on both FF and Chrome.

Comment: @D Franks - new solution allows closing when clicking outside the button -- but I can't close the menu *when clicking the button* - BTW thanks for your awesome help on this

Comment: Wow, sorry for all the confusion! The new fiddle above works in Chrome and FF, hides when clicking outside the nav, and toggles visibility when clicking an active element.

Comment: hey no problem - do you mean the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/znhAC/2/ -- this one still does not close menu on button click -- were you referring to another (newer) fiddle?

Comment: @D Franks - 1 more thing, looks like when I click on other elements of the page, like an unrelated button, your code triggers the `$(document).click...` part generating an error: `hide is not defined` - any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I see, add `var hide;` above `$(".toggle").click...`